# How to spot duplicates on multiple columns

Tags: r

Here is a dataframe with two columns and four rows

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,1)
month<-c(1,1,2,3)
mydata<-data.frame(ID,month)
```

I want to spot all the duplicated with the respect to the two variables, and here is the code I used:

```
mydata$dup<-duplicated(mydata["ID","month"])
```

I expected to have `True` for the second row as the second row is the repetition of the first one with respect to the two variables. But it is not the case. What is wrong with my code?

```
  ID month   dup
1  1     1 FALSE
2  1     1 FALSE
3  1     2 FALSE
4  1     3 FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to the absence of concatenation i.e. `c("ID", "Month")` - passing the column names as a vector

```
duplicated(mydata[c("ID","month")])
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

When we pass two elements, with `,`, the first one will be regarded as **row index/row name**, and the second as **column index/column name** and thus we got

```
duplicated(mydata["ID","month"])
[1] FALSE
```

which is recycled when we do the assignment (`<-`).

It is interesting to know the value extracted

```
mydata["ID","month"]
[1] NA
```

i.e., a missing value as the dataset doesn't have a row name 'ID' and column name 'month' both matching, thus returning a missing value.  When we apply the `duplicated` on a single value, it returns `FALSE`

---

This all relates to the usage in `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

where `i, j` are described as

> i, j, ...
> indices specifying elements to extract or replace. Indices are numeric or character vectors or empty (missing) or NULL. Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards zero). Character vectors will be matched to the names of the object (or for matrices/arrays, the dimnames): see ‘Character indices’ below for further details.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is as simple as that, you may be ok with a simple comparator:

```
mydata$dup<-mydata$ID==mydata$month
```

Or with dplyr:

```
mydata%>%mutate(dup = ID==month)
```